# Update Data on One Table Based on Another - SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

One is SUPPLIER with SupplierID as its PK and it has a State attribute.

The other is SUPPLIEDPART. It has a UnitCost attribute. SupplierID is a FK.

I'm trying to update the UnitCost based on whether or not the Supplier is located in the state of Texas. I have tried multiple queries, but they always fail. Here are some of the latest attempts. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached a picture of the relationship between the two tables if that will help.

```
INSERT INTO SUPPLIEDPART (UnitCost)
  SELECT UnitCost * 1.1
  FROM SUPPLIEDPART SP INNER JOIN SUPPLIER S
  ON SP.SupplierID = S.SupplierID
  WHERE State = 'TX';
```

----This one results in a "cannot insert nulls into brewer34.suppliedpart.supplierid

```
UPDATE SUPPLIEDPART
  SET UnitCost = UnitCost * 1.1
  WHERE SupplierID = (SELECT SupplierID
                     FROM SUPPLIER
                     WHERE State = 'TX')
  GROUP BY PartNumber;
```

----This query results in a command not properly ended----

[image]

Comment: What exactly has failed? Could you add the failure code(s) or resulting data example to your original post (OP)?

Comment: What DMBS are you using?

Comment: What does, "but they always fail" mean?  We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close:

```
UPDATE SUPPLIEDPART
SET UnitCost = UnitCost * 1.1
WHERE SupplierID IN (SELECT SupplierID    -- <-- IN instead of =
                 FROM SUPPLIER
                 WHERE State = 'TX')
-- no GROUP BY
```

Comment: Is the `GROUP BY PartNumber` valid?

Comment: That is what I expected, you just didn't call that out so I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely wouldn't have gotten that, even though I have used IN before. Not something I always know when to use yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On most DBMS you can do:

```
UPDATE SUPPLIEDPART AS a
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER AS b ON a.SupplierID = b.SupplierID
SET a.UnitCost = a.UnitCost * 1.1
WHERE  b.State = 'TX';
```

Comment: This command results in a "missing SET keyword." I don't think you can do inner joins on an update command or at least I couldn't get it to work. I am using SQL Developer. Not sure if that's the reason why.

Comment: Is that oracle? If so, then yes. it isn't supported. It is on Mysql and sql-server for example. Make sure you add the dbms on your question next time.